# React - Create objects from API call and store in one big object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a program that uses Axios to get data with API calls. I want to store the result as a object in my **this.state.matrixDictionary variable**. but everytime i make another API call the previous object gets overwritten. I want to create something like this

```
this.setState({
     matrixDictionary: {
       [0]: result,
     }
})
```

Then next time i make another api call to get other result i want it to be like this:

```
this.setState({
     matrixDictionary: {
       [0]: result,
       [1]: result,
     }
})
```

But i dont want to add the [1] manually, i want it to be created depending on how many times i make the API call to store the objects. If i make 5 calls then the object should be now [0],[1],[2],[3],[4] so i can easily keep track of the objects and change their values later.

How is this best achieved?

```
fetchDataAPI(APIUrl){


    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    console.log("Fetching from: " + APIUrl);

    return axios.get(APIUrl,{
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    })
        .then(result => {
            this.setState({isLoading: false});
            console.log(result.data);
            return result.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({error, isLoading: false })});

}
```

**UPDATE**

I used the fix from Roman Batsenko, Next question is how do I then change a property in that object and put it back in setState.

Comment: There is no way to achieve this. Either your API has to return the count how many times it get called? or keep track on UI side how many times fetchDataAPI is getting called.

Comment: Ok but how can i store several objects in 1 large object then?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react/43041334#43041334

Comment: @gtag, You can use array of objects and use Spread syntax as I've shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess good practice is to use JS [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for that like `...state`.
It depends on the format of answer from your API but I think it would be not so hard to achieve this with:

```
axios.get(APIUrl,{
    /* ... */
})
    .then(result => {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            matrixDictionary: [...this.state.matrixDictionary, result.data]
        });
    })
```

Comment: But first time its called this.state.matrixDictionary is null

Answer (score 0):

make an array of object in your intial state like

```
this.state = {
         matrixDictionary: []
      }
```

and when you call your api push your response object in array so that will store always in another index and finally you make array of objects.

```
this.setState({ matrixDictionary: result.data});
```

it may help you.

Comment: Using this method, the object gets overwritten when making another api call

Answer (score 0):

Why not save the objects in an array, so you can have them in order:

in the constructor:

```
this.state = {
  matrixDictionary: []
}
```

in your API call:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  values: prevState.matrixDictionary.concat(result.data),
}));
```

You can access them like this:

```
this.state.matrixDictionary[0] // your first api call
this.state.matrixDictionary[1] // your second api call
this.state.matrixDictionary[2] // your third api call
```

Comment: I get an empty list from this method

Comment: initialised in constructor as I said, and inside the API call (in the get response, first `.then`) called `setState`, and you get an empty list?